# Is it valid to use a repeated measures anova here?

Tags: r, anova

I have data that looks like this:

```
dat <- structure(list(id = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
1L, 1L), .Label = c("case", "ctrl"), class = "factor"), value = c(15.289966,
7.490917051, 47.45042784, 23.55192684, 91.4868866, 27.31247008,
31.59910658, 91.49867909, 42.47421666, 97.26971403), week = c(3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L)), .Names = c("id", "value",
"week"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

After browsing various stats blogs (as a non-statistician) I've come to believe a repeated measures ANOVA is the way forward. The Shapiro-Wilk p-value is 0.08356 so the data appears normal. The bar chart looks like there is a big difference between cases and controls.

[image: interaction plot] 
However I realise they can be misleading so I checked the interaction plot too, which looks significant too.

[image]

I then modelled the repeated measures ANOVA as:

```
ao = aov(value ~ id + Error(week), data=dat)
print(summary(ao))
```

which gives a p-value of 0.0662. Is this correct? I'm disappointed it's not significant but also skeptical that I've modelled it wrong. I don't just care about the difference over time, the main thing I want to see is if there's a case vs. control difference.

## Edit

values are optical density from a western blot

Cases = mouse cell line exposed to one condition

Controls = mouse cell line not exposed to condition

I want to assess if condition makes the protein aggregation differ over time between cases and controls. Two time points, 3 and 12 weeks. Multiple samples for all time points, except only 1 control for week 12.

Comment: Whether to use a repeated measures ANOVA depends entirely on how the data is collected (or the underlying model structure). Can you edit your question to explain what sort of experiment/survey your data represents?

Comment: ok sure, added a bit more detail.

Comment: 'Repeated' means that experimental unit has been measured more than once (in time here). What is your experimental unit ? And, do you have measured it multiple times ? It is not IMHO the data that should drive your choice of analysis, but the design of your experiment. Forget the data for a minute and think about what your design looks like and how you should analyse it logically. Then apply it to your data. Get the help of a statistician if you can.

Comment: I have multiple cases & controls at almost each time point, doesn't that mean that its measured multiple times? That's why I modelled it like that, value ~ id. Are you saying the result I got is correct?

Comment: @CianMurphy can I see your data ? and summary of output